# Log4Net - Don't Rollup Files

Tags: c#, log4net

I have Log4Net in my C# ASP.NET app.  I'm trying to not rollup files.  I want my log file created, and I want to simply keep adding to it until it reaches 10MB.  Right now, it is creating a new file per day which is what I don't want to do.  What am I doing wrong? Here's my Log4Net config settings.

```
<appender name="MigrationRequestPatternFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.PatternRollingFileAppender, CustomAppender">
  <file value="D:\RequestOutputFiles\%property{RqGuid}.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />  
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date %-5level %logger %-20M - %message%newline"/>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the file named?
And how is changing the property `RqGuid`?

*If* the property is changing at every restart and your server restarts nightly, we have the culprit.

If not, the problem is not where you are looking: you are not using the `RollingFileAppender`, but a `log4net.Appender.PatternRollingFileAppender, CustomAppender`. What is it and why are you using it?

You could just follow the example on the [log4net docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#RollingFileAppender):

```
<appender name="MigrationRequestPatternFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger %-20M - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And everything should just work.
(If there is a reason in using a Custom appender, we need to see the code and know the reason.)